# wget command still downloads folder after exclusion

Tags: wget

I am trying to learn wget better.  However when I run my code it still downloads the forum section.  Where am I going wrong?

```
    wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --limit-rate=50k --random-wait --exclude-domains http://domain.com/forums/ --no-parent http://domain.com/
```

[referenced](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`http://domain.com/forums/` isn't a domain, it's a URL.  `--exclude-domains` won't work with it.

Try `--exclude-directories=/forums/`.