# wget not excluding nested directory

Tags: wget

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61639/wget-command-still-downloads-folder-after-exclusion) but it's not working. The remote/ftp directory structure is this:

```
domain.com/
  toplevel/
    foo1/
      ARCHIVE/
        README.stuff
        DATA/
          README.txt
          ...other nested folders
      wantedstuff.zip
      wantedstuff2/
        morewantedstuff.zip
        ...otherstuffwanted
```

I want everything within `/toplevel` EXCEPT everything inside the `/ARCHIVE` folders for each nested folder in `/toplevel/*`.

I tried this:

```
wget --continue -r --exclude-directories=/ARCHIVE/ ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
```

and these:

```
wget --continue -r --exclude-directories=ARCHIVE ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
wget --continue -r --exclude-directories=ARCHIVE/ ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
wget --continue -r X /ARCHIVE/ ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
wget --continue -r -X '*/ARCHIVE/*' ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
wget --continue -r -X '*/ARCHIVE' ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
wget --continue -r --reject-regex '.*/ARCHIVE/.*' ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
```

But none seem to work, it still downloads that ARCHIVE folder. Wondering how to prevent it from downloading.

Comment: From your post, it sure looks like ARCHIVE is inside foo1, not toplevel. In which case, I would say your command is incorrect. Are you saying the tree is domain.com/toplevel/foo1/ARCHIVE or domain.com/toplevel/ARCHIVE?

Comment: it is `domain.com/toplevel/foo1/ARCHIVE `, but I am doing `wget domain.com/toplevel/`, because I want all the subfolders (and all their recursive content).

Comment: Then you still have to use the toplevel... I will answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the toplevel/foo. See a [previous example](https://serverfault.com/questions/324555/how-to-exclude-certain-directories-while-using-wget) The solution should be:

```
wget --continue -r --exclude-directories=/toplevel/foo/ARCHIVE/ ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
```

For some reason I prefer:

```
wget --continue  -X /toplevel/foo/ARCHIVE/ -r ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
```

To exclude all ARCHIVE directories in the first two top levels, do:

```
wget --continue  -X */*/ARCHIVE/ -r ftp://domain.com/toplevel/
```

but that is personal preference.

Comment: Thank you, will try around with that. In my system it would be more like `/toplevel/*/ARCHIVE`, wondering how to do that then (making it dynamic). Otherwise I might have to just copy/paste a thousand subfolders have a thousand wget commands in a script.

Comment: I _think_ you can try -X */*/ARCHIVE

Comment: Yay, `*/*/ARCHIVE` works.

Comment: Cool, I did not have my webserver at the moment to test. I will add that to my answer.